# Xamarin Forms date and time picker

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I am using Xamarin Forms to make Cross-platform application and I need to create simple view that user can choose date and time, similar to this: 
[View that I want to create](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A6XnN.png) that i found here: [Picker in Xamarin iOS](https://learn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/xamarin/ios/user-interface/controls/picker). Solution for Android is ready, but I need to create solution for iOS in the same application

I can not use standard date picker and another standard time picker separately from Xamarin Forms. I need to create custom solution (one view - simple choose both date and time).

I have tried to create view in Xamarin Forms that consist of 2 lists in horizontal orientation (one for date, one for time) but when I select one position, the list is not scrolling to the middle of view and also there is not auto-selecting middle position element when I scroll the list up or down. I want to create something that works like Xamarin-iOS solution: "Date and time picker" but in Xamarin Forms.

I have tried also to create in Xamarin-iOS part of project "date and time picker". I have main.storyboard and view controller but I dont know how to display view from Xamarin-iOS inside Xamarin Forms and pass selected date and time.

Can you help me, please?

Comment: welcome in SO! please read [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and correct your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to implement date-time picker on Xamarin.Forms in iOS platform.You can use [CustomRenderer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/custom-renderer/introduction).

> in Forms

create a subclass of `Picker`

```
public class MyPicker:Picker
{
    public MyPicker()
    {

    }
}
```

And add it in xaml

```
<StackLayout VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
    <!-- Place new controls here -->

    <local:MyPicker  WidthRequest="150"  BackgroundColor="AliceBlue"/>

</StackLayout>
```

> in iOS

create the renderer of `Picker` .And you can set the [format](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsdateformatter?language=occ) of picker as you want.

```
using System;

using Foundation;
using UIKit;
using ObjCRuntime;

using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS;

using xxx;
using xxx.iOS;

[assembly:ExportRenderer(typeof(MyPicker),typeof(MyPickerRenderer))]
namespace xxx.iOS
{
  public class MyPickerRenderer:PickerRenderer
  {

    string SelectedValue;

    public MyPickerRenderer()
    {

    }

    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Picker> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        if(Control!=null)
        {
            SetTimePicker();
        }

    }


    void  SetTimePicker()
    {
        UIDatePicker picker = new UIDatePicker
        {
            Mode = UIDatePickerMode.DateAndTime
        };

        picker.SetDate(NSDate.Now,true);

        picker.AddTarget(this,new Selector("DateChange:"),UIControlEvent.ValueChanged);

        Control.InputView = picker;


        UIToolbar toolbar = (UIToolbar)Control.InputAccessoryView;

        UIBarButtonItem done = new UIBarButtonItem("Done", UIBarButtonItemStyle.Done, (object sender, EventArgs click) =>
        {
            Control.Text = SelectedValue;
            toolbar.RemoveFromSuperview();
            picker.RemoveFromSuperview();
            Control.ResignFirstResponder();
            MessagingCenter.Send<Object, string>(this, "pickerSelected", SelectedValue);



        });

        UIBarButtonItem empty = new UIBarButtonItem(UIBarButtonSystemItem.FlexibleSpace, null);

        toolbar.Items = new UIBarButtonItem[] { empty, done };

    }

    [Export("DateChange:")]
    void DateChange(UIDatePicker picker)
    {
        NSDateFormatter formatter = new NSDateFormatter();

        formatter.DateFormat = "MM-dd HH:mm aa"; //you can set the format as you want

        Control.Text = formatter.ToString(picker.Date);

        SelectedValue= formatter.ToString(picker.Date);

        MessagingCenter.Send<Object, string>(this,"pickerSelected",SelectedValue);
    }
  }
}
```

And use `MessagingCenter` to pass the selected date and time.

```
public MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    MessagingCenter.Subscribe<Object, string>(this, "pickerSelected", (sender, arg) => {
        Console.WriteLine(arg);
        //arg is the selected date and time
    });

}
```

I have uploaded the demo on [github](https://github.com/luczha/PickerDemo) .You can download it for test.

[The effect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1c7iE.png)

Comment: How to use BindableProperty instead of MessagingCenter?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use native views in Xamarin.Forms it is possible, read it here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/platform/native-views/