# Xamarin Forms DateTimePicker custom ContentView bindable property

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, mvvm, datetimepicker

I build the following custom DateTimePicker, following the accepted answer from this post:[Xamarin forms DateTime Picker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60699446/xamarin-forms-datetime-picker) ,
in order to select a date and a time.

**DateTimePicker class:**

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace NativeTaskApp.Views.Component
{
    public class DateTimePicker : ContentView, INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public Entry _entry { get; private set; } = new Entry();
        public DatePicker _datePicker { get; private set; } = new DatePicker() { Date = DateTime.Today, IsVisible = false };
        public TimePicker _timePicker { get; private set; } = new TimePicker() { IsVisible = false };
        string _stringFormat { get; set; }
        public string StringFormat { get { return _stringFormat ?? "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm"; } set { _stringFormat = value; } }
        
        public DateTime DateTime
        {
            get { return (DateTime)GetValue(DateTimeProperty); }
            set { SetValue(DateTimeProperty, value); OnPropertyChanged("DateTime"); }
        }

        private TimeSpan _time
        {
            get
            {
                return TimeSpan.FromTicks(DateTime.Ticks);
            }
            set
            {
                DateTime = new DateTime(DateTime.Date.Ticks).AddTicks(value.Ticks);
            }
        }

        private DateTime _date
        {
            get
            {
                return DateTime.Date;
            }
            set
            {
                DateTime = new DateTime(DateTime.TimeOfDay.Ticks).AddTicks(value.Ticks);
            }
        }

        BindableProperty DateTimeProperty = BindableProperty.Create("DateTime", typeof(DateTime), typeof(DateTimePicker), DateTime.Now, BindingMode.TwoWay, propertyChanged: DTPropertyChanged);

        [Obsolete]
        public DateTimePicker()
        {
            BindingContext = this;

            Content = new StackLayout()
            {
                Children =
            {
                _datePicker,
                _timePicker,
                _entry
            }
            };

            _datePicker.SetBinding<DateTimePicker>(DatePicker.DateProperty, p => p._date);
            _timePicker.SetBinding<DateTimePicker>(TimePicker.TimeProperty, p => p._time);
            _timePicker.Unfocused += (sender, args) => _time = _timePicker.Time;
            _datePicker.Focused += (s, a) => UpdateEntryText();

            GestureRecognizers.Add(new TapGestureRecognizer()
            {
                Command = new Command(() => _datePicker.Focus())
            });
            _entry.Focused += (sender, args) =>
            {
                Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() => _datePicker.Focus());
            };
            _datePicker.Unfocused += (sender, args) =>
            {
                Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
                {
                    _timePicker.Focus();
                    _date = _datePicker.Date;
                    UpdateEntryText();
                });
            };
        }

        private void UpdateEntryText()
        {
            _entry.Text = DateTime.ToString(StringFormat);
        }

        static void DTPropertyChanged(BindableObject bindable, object oldValue, object newValue)
        {
            var timePicker = (bindable as DateTimePicker);
            timePicker.UpdateEntryText();
        }
    }
}
```

I also read through the Microsoft documentation (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/xaml/bindable-properties) about bindable properties and I think I have everything I need in my DateTimePicker class to use bindable properties. However, if i use the DateTime property in my xaml i get the following error: `No property, BindableProperty, or event found for "DateTime", or mismatching type between value and property`

**xaml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" 
             xmlns:common="clr-namespace:NativeTaskApp.Views.Partials" 
             xmlns:component="clr-namespace:NativeTaskApp.Views.Component"
             x:Class="NativeTaskApp.Views.CreatePage">
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout>
            <!--Header-->
            <common:TaskHeader/>
            <!--Fields-->
            <StackLayout Spacing="40">
                <StackLayout>
                    <Label Text="Titel" Style="{StaticResource main-label}"/>
                    <Entry Text="{Binding Task.Titel, Mode=TwoWay}" BackgroundColor="white"/>
                </StackLayout>
                <StackLayout>
                    <Label Text="Deadline" Style="{StaticResource main-label}"/>
                    <component:DateTimePicker DateTime="{Binding Task.Deadline, Mode=TwoWay}" BackgroundColor="white"/>
                </StackLayout>
                <StackLayout>
                    <Label Text="Schedule" Style="{StaticResource main-label}"/>
                    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Todo.Schedules, Mode=TwoWay}">
                        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <ViewCell>
                                    <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical">
                                        <component:DateTimePicker DateTime="{Binding Date, Mode=TwoWay}"  BackgroundColor="white"/>

                                    </StackLayout>
                                </ViewCell>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    </ListView>
                    <component:DateTimePicker DateTime="{Binding NewScheduleDate, Mode=TwoWay}"  BackgroundColor="white"/>
                    <Button BackgroundColor="Green" Text="Add Schedule" Command="{Binding AddScheduleCommand}" />
                </StackLayout>
                <StackLayout>
                    <Label Text="Description" Style="{StaticResource main-label}"/>
                    <Editor Text="{Binding Task.Description, Mode=TwoWay}" HeightRequest="500" BackgroundColor="white"/>
                </StackLayout>
            </StackLayout>
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

**Xaml BindingContext**

```
using NativeTaskApp.Services.GeneratedClients;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace NativeTaskApp.ViewModels
{
    public class CreateVM : BaseViewModel
    {
        /*Task.Schedules = new List<Schedule>*/
        /*Schedule.Date = DateTime*/
        public Todo Task { get; set; }
        public DateTime NewScheduleDate { get; set; }



        public Command AddScheduleCommand { get; }
        public CreateVM()
        {
            Task = new Todo();
            Task.Schedules = new List<Schedule>();
            NewScheduleDate = DateTime.Now;

            AddScheduleCommand = new Command(AddSchedule);
        }




        public void AddSchedule()
        {
            Task.Schedules.Add(new Schedule() { Date = NewScheduleDate });
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

### **1. DateTime as a bindable property**

Maybe I misunderstood the previous answer, but as a matter of fact, DateTime is a bindable property and we use it every day in a specific control in our mobile application.

Declaration example :

```
public static readonly BindableProperty MinimumDateProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(MinimumDate),
typeof(DateTime),
typeof(DateTime), default(DateTime), BindingMode.OneWay, propertyChanged: OnYearsRangeChanged);
```

And we consume it like this in our xaml :

```
<controls:MonthYearPicker 
 MinimumDate="{Binding TodayDateTime}"
 MaximumDate="{Binding ExitDateTime}"
 SelectedDateTime="{Binding SelectedExitLocalDate}"/>
```

As the Microsoft documentations states it :

> The purpose of bindable properties is to provide a property system that supports data binding, styles, templates, and values set through parent-child relationships.

As a consequence, as long as both binded properties have the same type, it should work flawlessly.

### **2. Proper declaration of bindable property**

When you have this `No property, BindableProperty, or event found for "DateTime", or mismatching type between value and property` error message :

- check the declaring type and the target type of your bindable property to detect any mismatch
- ensure that your BindableProperties are correctly declared. Especially be careful with the **access specifier** which should be public most of the time.

In your case your :

```
BindableProperty DateTimeProperty = BindableProperty.Create("DateTime", typeof(DateTime), typeof(DateTimePicker), DateTime.Now, BindingMode.TwoWay, propertyChanged: DTPropertyChanged)
```

Seems **internal and not public**: ([cf. official doc on access specifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/access-modifiers#class-and-struct-accessibility))

Add the public access specifier and see if the error message persists.

For example :

```
public static readonly BindableProperty DateTimeProperty = BindableProperty.Create("DateTime", typeof(DateTime), typeof(DateTimePicker), DateTime.Now, BindingMode.TwoWay, propertyChanged: DTPropertyChanged)
```

Comment: In addition to this answer, to use DateTime as a bindable property, delete the line BindingContext = this