# Can't get value of time on Xamarin DatePicker for iOS

Tags: ios, xamarin

I want to use Date and Time picker at the same time. But i can't get value of Time from Xamarin DatePicker just get Date value correctly.

I shared codes below

CustomDatePicker.cs

```
public class CustomDatePickerRenderer : DatePickerRenderer
{
    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<DatePicker> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);
        if(Control != null)
        {
            UITextField entry = Control;
            UIDatePicker picker = (UIDatePicker)entry.InputView;
            picker.PreferredDatePickerStyle = UIDatePickerStyle.Wheels;
            picker.MinimumDate = Foundation.NSDate.Now;
            picker.MaximumDate = Foundation.NSDate.Now.AddSeconds(172799);
            picker.Mode = UIDatePickerMode.DateAndTime;
        }
    }
}
```

Xaml

```
<DatePicker x:Name="datePickerIOS"  DateSelected="datePickerIOS_DateSelected" ></DatePicker>
```

Xaml.cs

```
private void datePickerIOS_DateSelected(System.Object sender, Xamarin.Forms.DateChangedEventArgs e)
{
   var date = datePickerIOS.Date;
   // This date's time value always return  12:00:00 AM
}
```

[image]

Comment: read the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.date?view=netcore-3.1) for the Date property - "A new object with the same date as this instance, and the time value set to 12:00:00 midnight (00:00:00)."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you use `DateSelected="datePickerIOS_DateSelected"` method,it was the event of the datepicker,you could only get the correct date.

You should get the correct date and time in your customrenderer and return it to your page(you could use [MessagingCenter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/messaging-center) to achieve this).

You could refer to this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55176321/10768653).